# How to structure dictionary to apply to function with enumerate

Tags: python, dictionary, tokenize, enumerate

I am trying to re-build a simple function, that ask for a dictionary as an input. No matter what I try I cannot figure out a minimum working example of a dictionary to pass through this function. I've read upon dictionaries and there is not so much room to create it differently, hence I do not know what the problem is.

I've tried to apply following minimum dictionary examples:

```
import nltk

#Different dictionaries to try as minimum working examples:
comments1 = {1 : 'Rockies', 2: 'Red Sox'}
comments2 = {'key1' : 'Rockies', 'key2': 'Red Sox'}
comments3 = dict([(1, 3), (2, 3)])

#Function:
def tokenize_body(comments):
    tokens = {}
    for idx, com_id in enumerate(comments):
        body = comments[com_id]['body']
        tokenized = [x.lower() for x in nltk.word_tokenize(body)]
        tokens[com_id] = tokenized
    return tokens

tokens = tokenize_body(comments1)
```

I know that with *enumerate* I am basically calling the index and the key, I can not figure out how to call the 'body', i.e the strings that I want to tokenize.

For both *comments1* and *comments2* with strings as inputs I receive the error: **TypeError: string indices must be integers**.

If I apply integers instead of strings, *comments3*, I receive the error:
**TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable**.

This may seem trivial to you, but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. If you could provide a minimum working example, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How about `for idx, (com_id, com_body) in enumerate(comments.items())`?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do here. Are you sure you want to pass in a dictionary, rather than a list? Enumerating a dict doesn't make much sense. And then once you're iterating, you then call `comments[com_id]` which ignores the enumerator completely. I don't think you actually want to enumerate at all. And further note, none of your dicts have a `body` key, so I don't know what you want to get there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman This is what strikes me as well. I do not understand where the 'body' key comes from. Moroever, I am not able to reconstruct any dictionary with a 'body' that works. I found the function from following github resporisory: [https://github.com/SmokinCaterpillar/doc2vec_user_comments/blob/master/Doc2VecUserCommentsAnalysis.ipynb] Unfortunately, there is no information about how the data is structured.

Comment: @Chris, this gives again: TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Comment: What makes you think those functions expect dictionaries? It looks to me as though they expect lists of dicts, so something like `[{'body': 'foo'}, {'body': 'bar'}]`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman. Fair point. I know it must be a dictionary, because the function prior to this (see github) builds up a dictionary that is then used. Trying lists of dict still gives the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Answer (score 1):

In order to loop through a dictionary in python, you need to use the `items` method to get both keys and values:

```py
comments = {"key1": "word", "key2": "word2"}
def tokenize_body(comments):
    tokens = {}
    for key, value in comments.items():
        # values - word, word2
        # keys - key1, key2
        tokens[key] = [x.lower() for x in nltk.word_tokenize(value)]
    return tokens
```

`enumerate` is used for lists, in order to get the `index` of an element:

```py
l = ['a', 'b']
for index, elm in enumerate(l):
    print(index) # => 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `.items()`, e.g.:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(comments1.items()):
    print(idx, item)
```

This will print

```
0 (1, 'Rockies')
1 (2, 'Red Sox')
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/IOHhV7).